# SD Card Reader issues with mbed OS 5/6

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, mbed

My coworker and I are having a rough time trying to get a [Sparkfun SD card breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12941) to function.

We got the SDBlockDevice example code to 'function', but upon runtime it would ruin the FAT32 filesystem of the sd card used? If the card was put back into Windows, it would require a reformat to use, and shows up in fdisk as 'RAW'.

We also tried using SDFileSystem, although it is deprecated.
When using SDFileSystem library:
Warning: L3912W: Option 'legacyalign' is deprecated.

[image: At run-time I get this error]

See: https://armmbed.github.io/mbedos-error/?error=0x80FF0100&tgt=DISCO_L475VG_IOT01A

When I import the example file for [SDFileSystem_HelloWorld](https://os.mbed.com/users/bikeNomad/code/SDFileSystem_HelloWorld/) I get the error "Error: Target "DISCO_L475VG_IOT01A" is not recognized". I believe this may bebecause of the code being intended for mbed OS 2.

We are using the DISCO L475VG IOT01A board.

If we are to continue with SDBlockDevice, is there a way to configure how it addresses formatting of the SD card? Also, is this mbed_app.json configuration correct:

```
    {
    "target_overrides": {
        "*": {
                "target.components_add" : ["SD"],
                "target.features_add": ["STORAGE"],
                "sd.SPI_MOSI" : "PA_7",
                "sd.SPI_MISO" : "PA_6",
                "sd.SPI_CLK"  : "PA_5",
                "sd.SPI_CS"   : "PA_15"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: With respect to SDFileSystem you have answered your own question there. It is probably a distraction from your original problem to even mention it, yet it takes up the bulk of your question. The link to the passive SD socket breakout board is not particularly useful. A link to the Discovery board would have been more useful as that is the active component, and a link to or the actual "_example code_" you mentioned even more so. Ultimately since it is most likely the code you are using is corrupting the card, and code is what SO is about, you need to post the code.

Comment: You posted a _picture of text_; don't do that.  Copy and paste the text _as text_ not an image.

Answer (score 0):

`SDBlockDevice` is *not* a filesystem.  It is a block device driver used to allow a higher layer filesystem in the software stack to access an SD/MMC card.

The example code at [SDBlockDevice](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v6.15/apis/sdblockdevice.html) only demonstrates the block-device API that must be used by a file system.  It does so by writing an ASCII string to what would be the boot-sector on a FAT formatted SD card.  Consequently it corrupts the formatting of such a card.

The point is that you do not use the SDBlockDevice to access teh SD card (unless you are implementing your own file system).  Rather, you include the Mbed [FATFileSystem](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v6.15/apis/fatfilesystem.html) component in your build and use the POSIX and standard library file I/O APIs to mount and access the file system.